# Can a database table work differently for each user?

Tags: java, database, javafx, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Im working on an employee management system using java and javafx.

im just wondering ;in this project there's an admin part and there's an employee part. Employees will sign up and login then after logging in they enter their personal details which will be kept on the database and then displayed on the dashboard.
So what i want to know is if i migrate the software and install it on another machine and enter my own details as an employee and then enter details on another machine.. will the dashboard on the second machine show the information from the first machine since the software uses the same table.

[image: screenshot]

I migrated the software to another machine unfortunately it didn't run because the machine did not have access to the database (another issue) so I couldn't find out exactly what I wanted thats why I came here

Comment: the table nor database have any say in what will be shown. That's decided by the code you write/execute. If you only do a "SELECT ID FROM TABLE", you'll only get the id, if you perform a "SELECT * FROM TABLE" you could show everything

Comment: If the database is embedded on the local machine, then no, changes by a client on one machine will not be seen by a client on another machine. However, if you have the database hosted on a server, and that server is reachable by all clients, then yes, changes by one client will be seen by the others. Though you will likely need to implement a "refresh" feature for the clients. In short, what matters is if you have "one" database or multiple _separate_ databases.

Comment: Crop your image.

Answer (score 3):

if the software running on both clients accesses the same database - if the database is on a central server, for example - if client 1 changes something in the database, the dashboard on client 2 will also be affected.

The software on both clients has the same data basis.

Depending on how your program is structured, you may have to make a commit after a change on client 1 so that the data is written to the database. And of course you have to update your scene in Java FX on client 2 so that the new data can be displayed.

Was that helpful?

Comment: Yes.. very clear and understandable

Answer (score 3):

"So what i want to know is if i migrate the software and install it on another machine and enter my own details as an employee and then enter details on another machine.. will the dashboard on the second machine show the information from the first machine since the software uses the same table."

This depends on how you move the software.

## Copy application to the new machine

If you copy the application such that it connects to the already existing database, you only have one set of data that you can view/modify from two clients. Any change done one one of those will be visible on the other as well.

## Copy application and database to the new machine

If you copy both application and database to a new machine and ensure each of the applications connect to their local database you have two sets of data. A change on one machine will affect the local database but not the one on the other machine.

## Move application to new machine

If you move the application it means you copy it over but remove the application on the first machine. I assume the database stays where it was.
This is a common pattern to separate application and database into different servers, possibly on different network segments.

Here you have only one client (the new machine you moved the application to) and one data set. Of course you can still view and edit it, but it will only be visible/editable on the new machine.